CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' after updating Azure.Identity package
After I updated Azure.Identity nuget package from 1.11.3 to 1.11.4 my project stopped to build. It's .NET MAUI application supporting both Windows and Mac. Problem appears with following line:
#if WINDOWS
    using System.Windows.Forms;
#endif

I am getting following error with that:
CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'

My project file:

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-maccatalyst;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    
    <OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyNamespace</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>Title</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>id</ApplicationId>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
</PropertyGroup>


Microsoft.Identity.Client references System.Windows.Forms #4468 --> Update changelog for Azure.Identity 1.10.4 with breaking changes (#44232)
